# Flutter re-rendering

Tags: javascript, flutter

I am developing a prototype application with flutter . One of the screens let users to update quantity and it's also is calling an endpoint.

I don't want to re-render the content of the screen after the user increase the quantity Here is my code any help will be appreciated

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class ProductDetailScreen extends StatelessWidget{
  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return  MaterialApp(

      title: "Product #1",

      home:Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar( title: const Text('Product #1', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepOrange)),
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.deepOrange),
            actions: <Widget>[

              IconButton(onPressed: (){
                ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                    const SnackBar(content: Text('This is a snackbar')));
              },icon: const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),color: Colors.deepOrange,)
            ],
            leading: BackButton(color: Colors.deepOrange,
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop())
        ),

        body:
        SafeArea(child: Center(
            child: ProductsDetailsScreen()
        ),

        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
class ProductsDetailsScreen extends StatefulWidget{
  const ProductsDetailsScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _ProductsDetailScreenState createState() => _ProductsDetailScreenState();
}


class _ProductsDetailScreenState extends State<ProductsDetailsScreen>
{
  int qty = 0;
void _increment(){
  setState((){
    qty = qty+1;
  });
}


  Future<List> fetchProduct() async{
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('https://www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/random.php'));
    final product = json.decode(response.body);
    List  prod = product['drinks'];
    List<Prod> prods = [];
    print(response);
    for(var p in prod){

      Prod product = Prod(idDrink: p["idDrink"],strDrink: p['strDrink'],strDrinkThumb: p['strDrinkThumb'] );
      prods.add(product);


    }
    return prods;

  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return
      Container(
          child:FutureBuilder(
              future  : fetchProduct(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot){

                if(snapshot.data == null)
                {
                  return Container(

                      child:Text("Loading...")
                  );
                }else {
                  return
                Column(
                    children: List<Widget>.generate(snapshot.data.length,(int index) {
                      return (

                            Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children :<Widget>[
                                Image.network(snapshot.data[index].strDrinkThumb,
                                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                                  ),
                                  Text(snapshot.data[index].strDrink.toUpperCase(),
                                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black,fontFamily: "Verdana",
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                  ),

                                  ),
                                  Text('49.00',
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepOrange,fontFamily: "Verdana",
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                    ),

                                  ),

                                Row(
                                    //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                children  :<Widget>[


                                  Expanded(
                                      flex:2,
                                      child:  ElevatedButton(
                                    onPressed: (){},
                                    child: Text('-'),
                                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary:Colors.deepOrange,
                                    ),)

                                  ),
                                  Expanded(
                                      flex:6,
                                      child: Container(alignment: Alignment.center,
                                          child:Text('$qty')),
                                    ),

                                  Expanded(
                                      flex:2,
                                      child:ChangeQuantity(_increment)
                                      // child:  ElevatedButton(
                                      //   onPressed:() =>{changeQty()},
                                      //   child: Text('+'),
                                      //   style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary:Colors.deepOrange,
                                      //   ),)

                                  ),
                                  ]
                                ),
                                Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                children:<Widget> [
                                  ElevatedButton.icon(
                                icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_basket_rounded),
                                onPressed: (){},
                                label: Text('Add to trolley'),
                                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary:Colors.deepOrange,
                                ),
                                )]
                                )

                                ],
                              
                              
                                )
                            );
                        }
                        )
                    );


                }}

          )

      );

  }
}

class ChangeQuantity extends StatefulWidget {
  final VoidCallback increment;

  ChangeQuantity(this.increment);
  @override
  _ChangeQtyScreenState createState() => _ChangeQtyScreenState();
}

class _ChangeQtyScreenState extends State<ChangeQuantity> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)   {
    return
      ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: widget.increment,
          child: Text('+'),
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary:Colors.deepOrange));
  }
}
```

This code is working but not in the manner i want. I found out that on increasing the quantity the page renders again and a call is made to the uri which renders the

Answer (score 0):

In _ProductsDetailScreenState for not re-rendering, move the List.generate to a statefulwidget. Pass the snapshot.data to that statefulwidget. Thus everytime you click on the increment button, this statefulwidget will reload and not the _ProductsDetailScreenState build method avoiding the API hit.

```
class _ProductsDetailScreenState extends State<ProductsDetailsScreen> {
    List<int> qty = [];

    ……..


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Container(
    child: FutureBuilder(
        future: fetchProduct(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data == null) {
            return Container(child: Text("Loading..."));
          } else {
            qty = List.filled((snapshot.data as List).length, 0);
            return CustomWidget(snapshot.data, qty);
          }
        }));
 }
}

class CustomWidget extends StatefulWidget {
final List<Drinks> drinks;
final List<int> qty;

CustomWidget(this.drinks, this.qty);

@override
State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _CustomWidgetState();
}

class _CustomWidgetState extends State<CustomWidget> {
_increment(int index) {
 setState(() {
   widget.qty[index]++;
   print(widget.qty[index]);
 });
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Column(
    children: List<Widget>.generate(widget.drinks.length, (int index) {
  return Expanded(
    child: (Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Image.network(
          widget.drinks[index].strDrinkThumb,
          fit: BoxFit.contain,
          width: 40,
          height: 40,
        ),
        Text(
          widget.drinks[index].strDrink.toUpperCase(),
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontFamily: "Verdana",
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          '49.00',
          style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.deepOrange,
            fontFamily: "Verdana",
            fontSize: 20,
          ),
        ),
        Row(
            //crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                  flex: 2,
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text('-'),
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Colors.deepOrange,
                    ),
                  )),
              Expanded(
                flex: 6,
                child: Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text('${widget.qty[index]}')),
              ),
              Expanded(flex: 2, child: ChangeQuantity(_increment, index)),
            ]),
        Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
            children: <Widget>[
              ElevatedButton.icon(
                icon: Icon(Icons.shopping_basket_rounded),
                onPressed: () {},
                label: Text('Add to trolley'),
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: Colors.deepOrange,
                ),
              )
            ])
      ],
    )),
  );
}));
}
}

class ChangeQuantity extends StatefulWidget {
final ValueChanged<int> increment;
final int index;

ChangeQuantity(this.increment, this.index);

@override
_ChangeQtyScreenState createState() => _ChangeQtyScreenState();
}

class _ChangeQtyScreenState extends State<ChangeQuantity> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {
      widget.increment(widget.index);
    },
    child: Text('+'),
    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.deepOrange));
}
}
```